# Toshiba model and serial number

Tags: toshiba-laptop

I'm using Toshiba Satellite and the serial sticker is already ruined. Can someone help me know how can i find the serial and model number? I opened the battery case and turned my laptop upside down but found nothing. Help please

Comment: There isn’t another way.

Comment: @Ramhound i lost the brightness adjustment and i'm using Windows 10. i need help with this. it's hurting my eyes...

Comment: I am not sure what the screen brightness has to do with the sticker but if your using 1809, and the brightness setting is resetting to 50% after you reboot, that’s a known bug which will be fixed next week

Comment: the adjustment was lost after the upgrade. I needed the model so i can have the original settings of my laptop and dload it again.

Comment: You don't need OEM software to change the brightness of your screen. You can control that natively within the Settings UWP application.  You typically only need the model of OEM device to find the software associated with the device.  Most OEM machines have something more than just a label that indicates the model number.

Comment: @Ramhound: Unless the brightness controller comes pre-broken from the OEM... My ASUS laptop, when running Windows, _only_ supports brightness control when using the old video driver from ASUS for this specific model. Whereas newer drivers from either AMD direct or Windows Update only have two options: 100% and 0%.

Comment: @Ramhound: And of course, the special **function keys** on the keyboard frequently require drivers to be recognized at all. They do on the ASUS (the ATKACPI thing), they do on the brand new HP...

Comment: @grawity - I didn't say the special keys didn't need drivers in order to function.  I was just giving a solution, since if the sticker can no longer be read, then it cannot be used to identify the model number.  Of course, I suspect the model number appears on the laptop in another location, other then a sticker, that is at least the case with Lenovo and Dell hardware I own.

Comment: Try the native Windows app  `msinfo32`

Answer (score 4):

Most laptops (and servers; less often desktops) have this information stored in the DMI data block.

From within Windows, you can retrieve it using:

- `wmic computersystem get manufacturer,model`
- `wmic bios get serialnumber`
- `wmic baseboard get serialnumber`
- `wmic <section> get /format:list`

For Linux the DMI information can be dumped using:

- `dmidecode`
- `cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_name`
- `cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_serial`
- `grep . /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/*`

(All commands require root or Administrator privileges.)

Comment: i will try this one. coz i lost the brghtness adjustment. i need the make and model of my Toshiba to download it again. if you know any other way where i can have the brightness adjustment back. pls help. i tried the Fn (f6, F7) not working